# Why jQuery Ajax is returning error 405 after many button clicks?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I am having a problem with jQuery Ajax in a Laravel Application.

The function:
Click button -> Executes Code
Repeats the proccess any times.

The function works fine, but the problem is that after some clicks (4/5), the code stop works and return this error:

`the get method is not supported for this route. supported methods post`

The code:

```js
$.ajax({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  url: "{{ route('controle.kanban.comercial.bipagem.processar') }}",
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  processData: true,
  data: $(form).serialize() + $("#form_processar_expedicao").serialize(),
  global: false,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
      if (data.card) {
        if (data.replace) {
          $("#" + data.replace).replaceWith(data.card);
        } else {
          $("#lista_processados").prepend(data.card);
        }

        $("#input_bipar_produto").val('').focus();
        $("#input_bipar_qtde").val('0');
        $("#bipar_div_lote").replaceWith('<div id="bipar_div_lote"></div>');
        check_qtdes_bipagem();
        init_form();
      }

      if (data.select) {
        $("#bipar_div_lote").replaceWith(data.select);
      }
    } else {
      if ($("#input_bipar_qtde").length) {
        p_validator.showErrors({
          'qtde': data.message
        });
      } else {
        p_validator.showErrors({
          'produto': data.message
        });
      }
    }

    $("#btn_processar").prop('disabled', false);
    return false;
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming that URL and request method are static, the problem probably much more likely is on the server side ...

Comment: Bring up the browser's developer console, and watch the Network tab as clicks are made. At any point does the POST request fail and it redirects to a GET request? If so, what is the error on the POST request?

Comment: There is something you are not showing us -or- @CBroe is correct in that something is wrong on the server-side because you're manually specifying a `POST` for the type.

Comment: is there any rate limiting going on?

Comment: Where i can get this information? In Kernel.php i have only: api => 'throttle:api',

Comment: Yes `throttle` is the name of the rate limiting middleware